# Vim Quickfix is always opening. Is there a way to get it open only if there are errors?

Tags: vim

I've created a function to execute make since I also want to redraw the screen. Quickfix opens after every execution even though I'm using the "cw" command. I'd like it to open only if there are errors. I know there is an error format setting - but it seems very complicated. Is there a simple way to set this up? I'm using clang as my compiler on OSX. Thanks.

```
command! -nargs=* Make call s:Make(<q-args>)
function! <SID>Make(args)
    execute "silent make " . a:args . " | cw"
    redraw!
endfunction
```

Comment: Does the quickfix window also open when there are no errors? Does it open when it's empty?

Comment: It opens with items - but the items are just compiler output, not errors. E.g.: || clang -Wall    foo.c   -o foo

Comment: Do I need to parse the output manually and add only error items?

Comment: You need to set a proper `'errorformat'` to make quickfix work. Either you find a good clang `:compiler` plugin for that, or write the errorformat yourself.

Comment: I should have specified that the items in quickfix are from the "make" output. If I run make -s, and if there are no errors, it works as I'd like. But there is also no output back in the shell  (:sh). So I guess I'd like make to run with output - but only populate quickfix with code errors.

Comment: Everything seems to be working as it should. Write a proper errorformat and you are good.

Comment: I played with the errorformat - it was a pain. I ended up just removing the invalid error lines from the qflist. Kinda brute-force, but it gives me a simple error list in qf and all the details back in the :sh. `call setqflist(filter(copy(getqflist()), 'v:val.valid == 1'))`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just removing the non-error lines from the qf list. The error lines that are left are formatted correctly and link back into the code as desired. This gives me a simple (bare bones) error list in qf and all the error details back in the :sh.

```
command! -nargs=* Make call s:Make(<q-args>)
function! <SID>Make(args)
    execute "silent make " . a:args
    call setqflist(filter(copy(getqflist()), 'v:val.valid == 1'))
    cw 
    redraw!
endfunction
```